# Nested <DIV> does not align to top

Tags: css

```
<div id="outer" style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%">

  <div id="1" style="position:relative; width:25%; height:auto;"></div>

  <div id="2" style="position:relative; width:65%; height:auto;">

     <div id="2a" style="position:relative; width:15%; height:auto;"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

The problem is that the #2 and #2a are not aligned to #1 and I have to use top:-xxpx to align to top.

http://jsfiddle.net/D7HZR/

Comment: What do you mean "not aligned to #1"?

Comment: did you reset your CSS so there won't be any margins and paddings?

Comment: There's no way to know what you mean by "align to top" or "align to #1", please revise. Default CSS might cause problems, so reset CSS could be a solution.

Comment: @EvanHahn check the Q pls

Comment: @X10nD please make a jsfiddle

Comment: @Roope : http://jsfiddle.net/D7HZR/

Comment: Okay, so you want the red box to be next to the yellow one? Is there a reason that you couldn't use `float: left;`on the `div`s?

Comment: @Roope I want the yellow and red box aligned to top inside the black box.  Both yellow and red should have a 2px space between them.

Comment: why you are not using float:left?

Comment: Also, please do not use numbers in the beginning of CSS id and class names. Don't know if it was just for this example or if you use those really, but please don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i think that i've understand your problem, just add the display property on your divs of id 1 and 2

```
<div id="outer" style="width:100%; height:400px; border:#000000 solid 1px;">

  <div id="1" style="display: inline-block; width:25%; height:400px; background:#fff000;"></div>

  <div id="2" style="display: inline-block;  width:65%; height:400px;background:#ff0000;">

     <div id="2a" style="width:15%; background:#000fff;"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p5KQJ/

Comment: falls apart when you put content into `2a`.

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D7HZR/1/). Is it what you are looking for?

```
#1, #2{
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Frankly speaking I'm not sure what you want. I think you want that :

```
<div id="outer" style="position:relative; width:100%; height:400px; border:#000000 solid 1px;">

  <div id="1" style="float:left; width:25%; height:400px; background:#fff000;"></div>

  <div id="2" style="float:left; width:65%; height:400px;background:#ff0000;">2

     <div id="2a" style="float:left; width:15%; height:auto;background:#000fff;">2a</div>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D7HZR/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
#outer div {
    float: left;
}
```

You also need to set a height on the inner div if you want it to take up vertical space.

It's unclear if you want the 3rd div nested or not so I made a fiddle that has one version nested and one with them all side by side.

[FIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/willthemoor/D7HZR/4/)